# Android Studio and Kotlin - not loading changes

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin

To load a fresh APK I am required to clean *every time* before building. It is like the compiler isn't noticing my code changes.

Here are my configurations:

- My project is entirely in Kotlin
- Kotlin version 1.1.60
- Gradle version 4.4
- Android Build Tools version 3.1.0-alpha04
- Android Studio 3.0 (stable)
- Java 8
- Databinding is enabled
- Using Kapt
- Instant run is disabled

I haven't confirmed if Java code would show the same problems or not.

Has anyone seen this and found a way around it?

Comment: what are you using kapt for ?

Comment: @crgarridos I am using kapt for Dagger and Android Lifecycle

Comment: Oh, and databinding